# Difference between these two for loops?

Tags: python

I would like to know how this loop:

```
def decrypt(s):
    l = [chr(ord(c)-2) for c in s]
    return ''.join(l)

print(decrypt("Ecguct"))
```

and this loop:

```
def decrypt(s):
    for c in s:
        l = chr(ord(c) - 2)
        return ''.join(l)

print(decrypt("Ecguct"))
```

are different from one another.

I haven't seen this format of looping — `[chr(ord(c)-2) for c in s]` — before, and if someone could tell me how to read it, I would be grateful.

Comment: A `return` inside a for-loop that is not in the scope of an if-statement is a very common programming error. It means the loop doesn't really loop but only executes the loop body once. Was there a typo in your question?

Comment: Hi Ray, thank you for your feedback. It is true that loop executes only once, however I cannot figure out why.

Comment: the second function should work with code like `result = ''` at the start, `result = result + l` in the loop, and `return result` after the loop... Or by constructing a list and the using the join. Here you exit at once and there isn't much to join...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second piece of code, you are returning `l` right after the first loop. At that point, `l`'s value is `['C']` and not `['Caesar']` as you were expecting.

```
def decrypt(s):
    for c in s:
        l = chr(ord(c) - 2)
        return ''.join(l) # -> this is the culprit

print(decrypt("Ecguct"))
```

`l = [chr(ord(c)-2) for c in s]` -> this is called a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).
It's a concise way of generating lists and is equivalent to

```
l = []
for c in s:
    l.append(chr(ord(c)-2))
```